# Sitecore MultilistField Image URL retrieval

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc, sitecore7.2

I have MultilistField in my Product Template, and datasource for multilist field is Images - i.e Product Images.

i want to retrieve the Image-URL from the Multilist field. can you please guide.

FYI, i dont have Glasmapper or TDS in my solution. can you provide basic sitecore approach

Answer (score 0):

Just use `GetItems()` method of `MultilistField` and then call `MediaManager.GetMediaUrl` method:

```cs
MultilistField mfField = Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["mf_field_name"];
foreach (var item in mfField.GetItems())
{
    var mediaUrl = Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(new MediaItem(item));
}
```